# leaflet.js: set max zoom level per layer?

Tags: maps, leaflet, cartodb

I am using CartoDB.js (3.15.9, based on Leaflet.js) with two map base layers, a street layer from CartoDB and a satellite layer from MapQuest:

```
  var options = {
    center: [53.2, -2.0],
    zoom: 6
  };
  var map = new L.Map('map', options);
  var streetLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
     attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors</a>'
  }).addTo(map);
  L.control.layers({
    'Map': streetLayer, 
    'Satellite': MQ.satelliteLayer()
  }, null, {'collapsed': false, 'position': 'bottomleft'}).addTo(map);
```

Can I set per-layer max zoom levels? I would like a max zoom of 18 on the street layer, and 21 on the satellite layer (this is because they have different max zoom levels available).

I tried setting `maxZoom: 18` on the `streetLayer` object, but this doesn't seem to do anything. The same option on `options` sets a global maximum zoom, but that obviously isn't what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you figured out, map's [`maxZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-maxzoom) option limits the navigation (the user cannot zoom higher than the specified level).

On a Tile Layer, the [`maxZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tilelayer-maxzoom) option defines up to which level the Tile Layer is updated on the map. Passed that level, the Tile Layer no longer updates, i.e. tiles are no longer downloaded and displayed.

You might be interested in using it in conjunction with the [`maxNativeZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tilelayer-maxnativezoom) option:

> Maximum zoom number the tile source has available. If it is specified, the tiles on all zoom levels higher than `maxNativeZoom` will be loaded from `maxNativeZoom` level and auto-scaled.

For example, for your street layer, you could set `maxNativeZoom` at 18 and `maxZoom` at 21.

Now if you want different navigation limits depending on what the map currently displays (for example if you have your 2 Tile Layers as basemaps in a Layers Control, so that they are not simultaneously displayed), you could use [`map.setMaxZoom()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-setmaxzoom) to dynamically change that limit when the user switches the basemap.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using maxNativeZoom as you suggested.